# How can I reset the scale of multiple video strips to 100% (the default) at the same time?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I've been editing a video in Blender and just noticed that the scale for all the video clips has been set to .444 (X and Y) when I actually want it to be 1.  I can do it manually but I'd prefer to know how to do it in one command for the future.  I tried selecting all the video strips and setting the property, but it only sets it for the "primary" selected video strip, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out right after posting this question.  Select all the video clips by dragging a selection box across all of them, then press F3 to bring up the search bar and type 'scale', and select `Image -> Clear -> Scale`.

[image]

Comment: also worth noting that with all the clips selected, changing a setting whilst holding ALT should change it on all clips

Comment: wow that's a much better solution, if you post it as an answer I'll change the question to be more general and accept your answer.

Comment: well, to be fair it's probably a duplicate, but you could add that to your answer and accept it

Comment: I don't understand; what is a duplicate of what?